# Latex: enumerating in multicols gives unwanted whitespace between lines

Tags: latex, multicol

I am trying to set up a multiple answer sheet with several short answers, but when I try to use the multicol environment, it creates unwanted whitspace.

The code is

```
\documentclass[11pt,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{multicol}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\summation}[2]{\sum\limits^{#1}_{#2}}

    
\textbf{11)} The expression $\frac{\sin{x} + \sin{y}}{\cos{x} + \cos{y}}$ is equal to
    \begin{enumerate}[(A)]
    \begin{multicols}{2}
            \item $\tan{\frac{x + y}{2}}$ % CORRECT
        \item $\tan{\frac{x - y}{2}}$
        \item $2\tan{x + y}$
        \item $2\tan{x - y}$
        \item $2\tan{2 x y}$
        \end{multicols}
    \end{enumerate}
```

and it looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/id8ao.png)
Any advice on how to solve the issue?

I tried using the multicols* environment, but it caused the page to contain only the answer columns.

Comment: If you cross-post the same question on multiple sites, you should include links to all other versions of the question in every question. X-posting without explicit links has the risk of wasting both the time of users who might put time and effort into answering a post, which already has an answer elsewhere, as well as the time of users who might have the same problem but can't find the solutions you might have gotten on one of the other sites you x-posted your question

Comment: x-post https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/708331/36296

Comment: Incidentally, there is no *environment* called `multicol`. The name of the environment is `multicols`.